# Hibernate Search IndexedEmbedded Out Of Memory

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two entities (entityA and entityB), one which contain another with @IndexedEmbedded, because when I search, I want to query by entityB as well, and return entityA.

The relationship (simplified) is as such:

```
public class EntityA {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<EntityB> children;
}

public class EntityB {
    @ManyToOne
    @ContainedIn
    private EntityA parent;

    private String childName;
}
```

I am having issues now because relationally, the "children" in entityA can have up to 100k items. This causes OutOfMemory issue no matter if I am using FullTextSession.index or the MassIndexer.

I could actually remove the @OneToMany mapping in EntityA because when I want to access EntityB, I will usually do a query with some filtering and pagination, but if I remove the @OneToMany, then Hibernate Search will not index my EntityB.

Is there anyway to get the FullTextSession.index to perform indexing based on batch on the "children"?

Comment: How about increasing JVM memory?

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a solution that can scale, to bigger amount of items.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should remove that relationship like one to many and many to one and write a join query to fetch the results of desired size, fetching 100k rows kills the mem.

Thnx,
Subhash

Comment: yeah, but how do I still enable the search by entityB if I remove the relationship? That's my question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the queries you want to effectively execute, you might be able to reverse the indexing.
Instead of parking EntityA as `@Indexed`, you mark EntityB as `@Indexed` and mark its parent association with `@IndexedEmbedded`.

That way, you won't suffer from having to load the 100k elements.

On the query side, you will need to reverse your query as well to something like `childName:Emmanuel AND parent.name:Hardy`
What you will receive is EntityB instances but you can reach EntityA by simple navigation, or by using a [`ResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#_resulttransformer).

Note that if your link between EntityB and EntityA is lazy, you can ask Hibernate Search to adjust its [fetching strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#_building_a_hibernate_search_query):

`Criteria criteria =
    s.createCriteria(EntityB.class).setFetchMode("parent", FetchMode.JOIN);
s.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery).setCriteriaQuery(criteria);`

Comment: Can you elaborate the "reach EntityA by simple navigation"? As I understand ResultTransformer works on the whole results as a List, so I assume it will have performance issues as well if the returned results is huge.

Comment: True. If the list of results is huge and your `@ManyToOne` is lazy, use the criteria approach I showed to make sure they are loaded in a single query. But really, you should not return a huge list of results. Use pagination `setMaxResult` and co.